# How accessing a specific feature and comparing it with the next one?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, attribute-table

Let's imagine to have a vector layer whose attribute table is made of an **ID** field, a field "A" (**string**) and a field "B" (**float**).

I am trying to access a specific feature (e.g. [0]) in field A, comparing the selected value with the one after([1]) in the same column and, based on this, doing something.

If I were working on a spreadsheet, I'd write: **IF(A0=A1; B0=x;"")**.
Based on the final hint enclosed in a previous discussion ([link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/138624/how-to-access-a-specific-feature?answertab=votes#tab-top)), which is quite closed, I tried to use it but:

- it moves among fields (horizontally) and not features (vertically)
- and I should activate it for each feature (but what about if there are many features?)

**SCRIPT TRIAL:**

```
features = layer.getFeatures()
attrs = feat.attributes()
attr = attrs[0]
Index=2 # field index
request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFid(0) 
#feature index
feat = layer.getFeatures(request).next()
print feat.attributes()[Index] 
#thus, the result returned is the first feature in third field
Index=Index+1
#I change the index to the 1st.one on the right
print feat.attributes()[Index] 
#thus, I obtain the 1st feature of the 4th field
```

Comment: Please format your code with the `{}` button. If you take the [Tour] you'll see that paragraphs with greetings and thanks are considered distractions from the problem statement.

Comment: How many _rows_ do you have in your layer?

Comment: @mgri Number of rows: thousands...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Oscar Campolmi who helped me, a possible script could be:

```
listLayers = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values() 
    for layer in listLayers:
            field_index_nome = layer.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex('Name')
            field_index_numero =layer.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex('Number')
            field_index_somma = layer.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex('Sum')


            unique_values = layer.uniqueValues(field_index_nome, limit=1001)

            layer.startEditing()
            for val in unique_values:
                count = 0
                features = layer.getFeatures()
                for f in features:
                    if f[field_index_name] == val:
                        number = f[field_index_numero]
                        count = count + number
                        layer.changeAttributeValue(f.id(), field_index_somma, count)

            layer.commitChanges()
```